# Non-Uniqueness of Basis in a column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -5 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ I know that $span(A)$ has basis
$$
Basis = \{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4\\-5\\3\\-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\}
$$ We know that basis is not unique. Question: Which two columns of $A$ must be included in all the bases that will span the column space of $A$? I'm kinda confused but I think it's related to the scaling of this basis ? Thank you.

Comment: Your Basis  is that of the Span of the column space of A. Why must 2 columns in A be special? Any 4 linearly independent combinations formed from your Basis will also be a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ be the columns of your matrix. We can see that

1. $\operatorname{Dim}\operatorname{span}(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=4$.
2. $a_4=-a_1-a_2$.

It follows that the basis consists of four columns and cannot contain three columns $a_1,a_2,a_4$ at the same time. Therefore $a_3$ and $a_5$ lie in any basis chosen among the columns of $A$.

Comment: Question is not properly worded. First there’s no span for matrix A. Second the number of bases is uncountable. You must specify that the basis should be from among the columns of A to make your question meaningful.